# vue.js | TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

Tags: node.js, express, vue.js

I'm trying to make email verification in my vue.js/express app.
I can create the user and send emails. But showing a message like "verification mail sent" won't work.

The error occurs when executing the code in the then() callback after the execution in DataService.

When registering the following functions are executed:

1. vuex

   ```
   const actions = {
   registerUser({
    commit
   }, user) {
    commit('registerRequest', user)

    return DataService.registerUser(JSON.stringify(user))
      // HERE'S THE ERROR
      .then(response => {
        commit('confirmation', response.message)
        setTimeout(() => {
          state.status = {
            confirmHere: ''
          }
        }, 4000);
      })
      .catch(...)
   ```

confirmation:

```
confirmation: (state, msg) => {

    state.status = {
      confirmHere: msg
    }
  },
```

2. DataService

   ```
   registerUser(user) {
   // Send email for registration
   apiClient.post('/user/register/sendMail', user)
    .then(res => {
      return apiClient.post(`/user/register`, user)
    })
    .catch(err => {
      throw err;
    })
   ```

   },

The `sendmail` function is using nodemailer to send an email and returns

```
  res.status(200).json({
    message: "success"
  });
```

The register function in express is:

```
router.post('/register', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    if (req.body.username !== undefined && req.body.password !== undefined) {
      let password = await bcrypt.hashSync(req.body.password, saltRounds);

      let compareUser = await db.getObject({}, User, 'SELECT * FROM app_users WHERE username=? LIMIT 1', [req.body.username]);
      if (compareUser !== undefined) {
        res.status(409).json('User already exists');
        return;
      }

      const tmp = {
        username: req.body.username,
        password: password
      };

      await db.query('INSERT INTO app_users SET ?', [tmp]);
      let user = await db.getObject({}, User, 'SELECT * FROM app_users WHERE username=? LIMIT 1', [req.body.username]);
      if (user === undefined)
        res.status(500).json('Internal server error');

      res.status(201).json({
        "message": "Bestätigungs-Email gesendet."
      });
    } else {
      res.sendStatus(400);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    res.sendStatus(500);
  }
});
```

Comment: You need to add `return` before `apiClient.post....` in `registerUser`. It doesn't return anything.

Comment: @ginga_ninja217 Always the small things. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to `return` the response from `DataService.registerUser`

```
// DataService.js
registerUser(user) {
 // Send email for registration
 return apiClient.post('/user/register/sendMail', user)
   .then(res => {
     return apiClient.post(`/user/register`, user)
   })
   .catch(err => {
     throw err;
   })
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that your registerUser function doesn't return anything whereas you're expecting it to return a promise.

Change your registerUser to:

```js
registerUser(user) {
  // Send email for registration
  return apiClient.post('/user/register/sendMail', user)
   .then(res => {
     return apiClient.post(`/user/register`, user)
   })
}
```

(FYI in the example, I left the .throw out because it already gets handled by the Promise you return ;)